# Jquery Information map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the map on the [Visit Norway Website](http://www.visitnorway.com/)

I have looked at a number of plugins to get me started like j vector maps, ammaps and imagemapmaster.

Image Map Master seems to be the most fitting for what I need. I think I will use this but I was wondering? Does anyone know what plugin was used to create this map on the Visit Norway website.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The awesome Dojo toolkit.**

There's **Dojo SVG**, **Dijit components** and more in that map.
See all in Chrome > inspector (F12) > Sources.

Answer (score 0):

The Map Functionality is coming from this file:

http://www.visitnorway.com/js/module_mapcomponent_viewer.min.js

And the link position on map(Blue icon), the data on popup (title, img URL, Description, etc) is coming from a JSON file:

http://www.visitnorway.com/WebServices2/JsonServices.asmx/GetMapComponentData?pageId=11818&languageCode=%22en%22&isMice=false&enableBooking=true

Please use any JS Beautifier service to see the actual code.